# How to pass argument to method defined in controller but called from directive in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try to pass one parameter from directive to method defined in controller.

I use isolate scope.

Here is relevant code and [Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dNYzQ/99/):

**HTML**

```
 <div ng-controller="MapCtrl">
        <map id="map_canvas" call='callMe()'></map>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
var module = angular.module('googleMap', []);

module.directive('map', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope:{
            callMe : '&call'
        },
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(element);

           /* ... */                
           scope.callMe('hey');

           /* ... */                                
        }
    };
});

function MapCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.callMe = function(val){
    alert(val);
    };

}
```

Why  I get `val=undefined`? It should be `hey`

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to annotate your function parameters:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Zy2yu/)

View:

```
<map id="map_canvas" call='callMe(param)'></map>
```

Directive:

```
scope.callMe({param: 'hey'});
```

This is [explained in the docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/docs/api/ng.%24compile#-scope-) (although somewhat vaguely):

> & or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of
>   the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name
>   is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: {
>   localFn:'&myAttr' }, then isolate scope property localFn will point to
>   a function wrapper for the count = count + value expression. Often
>   it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression
>   and to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of local
>   variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example,
>   if the expression is increment(amount) then we can specify the amount
>   value by calling the localFn as localFn({amount: 22}).