# Passing a callback form directive to controller function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have a directive and a controller. The directive defines a function in its isolate scope. It also references a function in the controller. That function takes a callback. However, when I call it from the directive and pass in a callback, the callback is passed through as undefined. The code below will make this more clear:

Directive

```
directive('unflagBtn', ["$window", "api",
    function($window, api) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: "<a ng-click='unflag(config.currentItemId)' class='btn btn-default'>Unflag</a>",
            require: "^DataCtrl",
            scope: {
                config: "=",
                next: "&"
            },
            controller: ["$scope",
                function($scope) {
                    $scope.unflag = function(id) {
                        $scope.next(function() { //this callback does not get passed
                            api.unflag(id, function(result) {
                                //do something
                                return
                            });
                        });
                    };
                }
            ]
        };
    }
]);
```

Controller

```
controller('DataCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'api', 'dataManager', 'globals',
    function($rootScope, $scope, api, dataManager, globals) {
        ...
        $scope.next = function(cb) { //This function gets called, but the callback is undefined.
            // do something here 
            return cb ? cb() : null;
        };
    }
]);
```

HTML

```
<unflag-btn config="config" next="next(cb)"></unflag-btn>
```

I've read here [How to pass argument to method defined in controller but called from directive in Angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401308/how-to-pass-argument-to-method-defined-in-controller-but-called-from-directive-i)  that when passing parameters from directives to controller functions, the parameters need to be passed in as objects. So I tried something like this:

```
$scope.next({cb: function() { //this callback does not get passed still
    api.unflag(id, function(result) {
        //do something
        return
    });
}});
```

But that did not work. I am not sure if this matters, but I should note that the directive is placed inside a form, which in its place is inside a controller. Just to illustrate the structure:

```
<controller>
   <form>
        <directive>
   <form>
<controller>
```

Hope this is clear and thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do. Are you trying to pass a regular controler to a directive. when using required you are getting the controller of in this case a parent directive. Is a way to communicate between directive. Can you explain what are you trying to do.

Comment: The function next() is in a controller and it controls the view. It takes a callback. I am trying to have different directives access that function. I am doing it this way because I want different directives to pass different callbacks to the function depending on what I need to do. But for some reason when I call next from a directive and pass it a callback, when the controller receives the call the callback is undefined... I hope this makes it more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I unintentionally figured out whats wrong after not being able to pass an object back to the controller as well. What happened, (and what I probably should have mentioned in the question had I known that its relevant) is that the parent scope of this directive `unflagbtn` is actually the scope of another directive that I have, call it `secondDirective`. In its turn the `secondDirective` is getting its scope from "DataCtrl". Simplified code looks like this:

```
directive("secondDirective", [function(){
    require: "^DataCtrl" // controller
    scope: {
        next: "&" // function that I was trying to call
    }
    ...
    // other code
    ...
}]);

directive("unflagbtn", [function(){
    require: "^DataCtrl" // controller 
    scope: {
        next: "&"
    }, 
    controller: ["$scope", function($scope){
        $scope.unflag = function(){
            $scope.next({cb: {cb: callBackFunctionIWantedToPass}); // this is what worked
        }
    }
}]);
```

So passing a callback in that manner solved my problem as it made its way back to the controller. This is ugly most likely due to my poor understanding of angular, so I apologize as this is most likely not the correct way to do this, but it solved my problem so I though I'd share.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        controller: ["$scope",
            function($scope) {
                $scope.unflag = function(id) {
                    $scope.next({
                        cb: function() { //this callback does not get passed
                            api.unflag(id, function(result) {
                                //do something
                                return;
                            });
                        }
                    });
                };
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. But this did not work... when the controller receives the call for next() cb is still undefined.