# Scope function isn't receiving a callback argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a controller like this:

```
angular.module('main', []).controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.doStuff = function (cb) {
        // Do some stuff.
        cb();
    };
});
```

And I have a directive like this:

```
angular.module('action-bar', []).directive('actionBar', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        template: '<h1>test</h1>',
        scope: {
            doStuff: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.doStuff(function () {
                alert('callback executed');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here is the markup:

```
<div ng-app="main">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div ng-action-bar></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can call `doStuff` just fine, however the `cb` argument is always `undefined` even though I'm passing in an anonymous function as the callback. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you actually pass the `doStuff` attribute to your `actionBar` directive in your HTML? You didn't give us a sample of how you are using it.  Just from a quick glance I think you need to add a `doStuff="doStuff()"` to your HTML.. or just create a jsfiddle so we can see it better

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass argument to method defined in controller but called from directive in Angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401308/how-to-pass-argument-to-method-defined-in-controller-but-called-from-directive-i)

Comment: @JoseM Sorry, I left out the markup. The directive is contained within the element that is controlled by `mainCtrl`. Therefore the `doStuff` function is inherited into the isolate scope from the controller scope.

Comment: @Stewie this is not a duplicate because I am not trying to pass anything in through `attrs`. I'm simply trying to pass an argument to the parent scope method from within the link function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your isolate scope to use `=` instead of `&` allows you to access the parent scopes doStuff method.

```
angular.module('main', ['action-bar']).controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.doStuff = function (cb) {
        // Do some stuff.
        cb();
    };
});

angular.module('action-bar', []).directive('actionBar', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        template: '<h1>test</h1>',
        scope: {
            doStuff: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.doStuff(function () {
                alert('callback executed');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Using the directive in you markup

```
<div ng-app="main" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <action-bar do-stuff="doStuff">
    </action-bar>
</div>
```

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/RsUwC/).

Comment: So, it looks like if you don't include the `do-stuff="doStuff"` attribute then it doesn't work. Is there a way to make this possible without specifying any attributes in the markup?

Comment: Sure if you remove the isolate scope e.g(`scope: { doStuff: '=' },`) it should work without having to pass in the method as a parameter.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HU4gC/)

Comment: I guess I can't do that because my team has their reasons for having the isolate scope. I think my big failure here was that I didn't know about `scope.$parent`, which I just discovered. Calling `scope.$parent.doStuff(function () { ... })` seems to work just as expected :)

Comment: That works as well, Although using `$parent` can cause headaches in certain cases.

Comment: I can see that, but in this case I literally am trying to call a simple parent function from inside an isolated scope. I don't actually need the parent function to be in the isolated scope at all. This seems like the "proper" solution, if there even is one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the expression ('&') syntax for passing doStuff into your directive then in your html you should pass it in like this:

```
<div action-bar doStuff="doStuff(cb)"></div>
```

and in your directive's link function you can call it like this:

```
scope.doStuff({cb: function() { ... }});
```

Checkout the egghead.io video on it for more info: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-expression-binding

Note: I personally don't like this syntax so I always use Jonathan Palumbo's solution (two way binding).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply using `scope.$parent` to access the parent scope. I don't actually need the parent function to be part of the directive's isolate scope.

Example:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

// Main controller.
app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  // Initial text added to log.
  $scope.logs = ['App loaded.'];
  // A log function to add additional lines to the log.
  $scope.log = function (text, callback) {
    $scope.logs.push(text);
    if (callback) callback();
  };
});

// Directive to log lines to the log viewer.
app.directive('ngLogLine', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="msg" ng-keydown="$event.keyCode === 13 ? log() : null" /><button ng-click="log()">send</button></div>',
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      // Create our own log function on our isolate scope.
      scope.log = function () {
        // Call parent log function and pass in a callback.
        scope.$parent.log(scope.msg, function () {
          // Clear the msg, clearing the input.
          scope.msg = '';
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/eHuaK/