# pass arguments to a function call in a directive via angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive. In my html i write this:

```
<uploader action="/rest/file/create_from_form.json" success="writeFid()"></uploader>
```

What I need is to exec "success" attribute function passing some data that I get from my directive. I can exec "success" attribute function via

```
$scope.$eval($scope.success)
```

and in my "controller" I have this:

```
$scope.writeFid = function (data) {
        console.log("Into writeFid");
        console.log(data);  //this is my problem: it is always undefined.
    }
```

I can see (via console.log() messages) that "success" function is called but without passing "data".

I have tried to use

```
<uploader action="/rest/file/create_from_form.json" success="writeFid(data)"></uploader>
```

but it does not work.

So: how can i pass some type of $scope.data ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your directive use an isolate scope?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass argument to method defined in controller but called from directive in Angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401308/how-to-pass-argument-to-method-defined-in-controller-but-called-from-directive-i)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether your directive uses an isolate scope or not, so I'll cover both cases:

**Without an isolate scope:**

```
scope.$eval(attrs.success, { data: 'Some value from foo' });
```

**With an isolate scope:**

```
scope: { success: '&' },
...
scope.success({ data: 'Some value from bar' });
```

Regardless of the type of the scope, your markup must be like this:

```
<uploader success="writeFid(data)" ...></uploader>
```

And here's a [plunk script](http://plnkr.co/edit/U7pMAmlWlCCk5cYgVAcZ?p=preview) showing both approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an isolate scope with a bi-directional binding in your uploader directive to somewhat achieve what you're after.

**uploader directive**

```
...
scope: {
    data: '=',
    success: '&'
}
...
```

***Sample parent controller***

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.dataAttribFromParent = { data: [] };

   $scope.writeFid = function () {
       console.log($scope.dataAttribFromParent);
   };
});
```

**markup**

```
...
<uploader data="dataAttribInParent" success="writeFid()">
...
```

Here's a plunk to elaborate:

http://plnkr.co/edit/7Kzy6D7cwxlATEBKRcuT